# fixed relative container i am confused how to do this

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]I have big doubt about `fixed`, `relative` , `absolute` container

I have a `css` code like this

```
.header {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:60px;
}
.page, .footer {
position:relative;
width: 80%;
min-width: 980px;
max-width: 1366px;
}
```

and my `html` code like this...

```
<div class="header">--fixed content--</div>
<div class="page">--page content</div>
<div class="footer">--footer content--</div>
```

I have used `bootstrap` for button styles. problem is the `header div` is `fixed` but the content inside the `page` & `footer` goes over the header content. When I remove `position:relative;` from `page` & `footer` css it works fine. But also `bootstrap buttons` goes still goes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.header {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.page {
  position:relative;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 980px;
  max-width: 1366px;
  background: #999;
  height:500px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin: auto;
}
.footer {
  position:relative;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 980px;
  max-width: 1366px;
  background: #666;
  height:100px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/728dyfnk/1/)

Adding a z-index will keep your header always on top of other content. You can change its value as per your content.
add the padding-top to your '.page' to avoid any overlapping of header on the body content.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using like this:

```
.header {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  z-index: 99999999;/*adding higher index value than other divs*/
  /* This will ensure the header div always on top of other divs */
}
.page{
  position: relative;
  top: 61px;/* plus 1px height as of .header or use as per your requirement */
  /* but at least this should be 60px to show your .page div */
}
```

Then, just other divs you don't need to define the top value for this issue(overlaps).

Comment: i have tried margin-top:65px; (or) top:61px; it does only the hidden values backside the header container... but my problem is the content in tha page goes top over the header not backside.

Comment: Updated my answer as per your comment. Read comments in my answer.